# When debugging F#, can you skip the last statement of a function?

Tags: debugging, f#, visual-studio-debugging, c#-to-f#

In C# if I want to skip the last statement of a method in the debugger I can put the cursor on the ending curly brace of the method and right-click and choose `Set Next Statement (Ctrl+Shift+F10)`.  In F# since there is no curly brace is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! I don't think there's an exact equivalent in F#, since it doesn't have curly braces and it also doesn't really have "statements" in the same way C# does.

If you're wanting to do this to return to the caller of the method/function you're currently inspecting in the debugger, you could just use `Step Out (Shift+F11)` -- it'll finish executing and return from the current method/function, then break.